# Ошибка "Resetting from a cold boot. Emulation Engine failed."

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, эмулятор, android-emulator

С сегодняшнего дня перестал работать эмулятор андроида, выдает ошибку "Resetting from a cold boot. Emulation Engine failed."
Пользовался им только для React Native.

**Методы которые я уже перепробовал:**

1. Полная переустановка Andriod Studio
2. Вывод emulator -avd Pixel2 -no-snapshot-save в CLI
3. Wipe Data -> Cold boot now

Ничего!!! не помогло. Мне сейчас очень важно, чтобы эмулятор заработал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы пробовали [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58904249) и [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319451) варианты?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Не получилось ничего. До сих пор проблема актуальна